# Zopim Bubble hides when screen is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a wordpress website with Zopim Live Chat installed, but when I resize the browser it hides the Zopim Bubble. What should I change in my code, so it stays visible at all times?

```
<!--Start of Zopim Live Chat Script-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.$zopim || (function(d, s) {
        var z = $zopim = function(c) {
                z._.push(c)
            },
            $ = z.s =

            d.createElement(s),
            e = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        z.set = function(o) {
            z.set.

            _.push(o)
        };
        z._ = [];
        z.set._ = [];
        $.async = !0;
        $.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');

        $.src = '//v2.zopim.com/?zopim_secret_key';
        z.t = +new Date;
        $.

        type = 'text/javascript';
        e.parentNode.insertBefore($, e)
    })(document, 'script');
</script>
```

Comment: This code doesn't help a bit. If it's hidden, why not just show it on resize completion?

Comment: This ... code ... ouch ...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's set to hide on mobile? Check your settings in the Zopim dashboard!